# random error when parallel bundle install in ruby

Tags: ruby, random, bundler, parallels

I use jenkins's master/slave to parallel run testcase writen with rspec. In each slave, I setup 8 executors, and each executor will run such command in the same time:
gem install bundler &
bundle install &
rake rspec ...

Random errors happens when it executes "bundle install", and all of them is about "cannot load such file --- <%file_name%>". This random error frequency is very low (happens once in about 50 times bundle install) and the <%file_name%> in errors is quite different: this time is "bundler/index", and that time can be another, for example, "bundler/vendor".

I am not sure whether it is caused by parallel running "bundle install". Is anyone meet similar problems?

Here is my environment:

The OS of each slave: CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643)

Bundler version: 1.3.5

Rspec verison: 2.12.2

RVM version: 1.18.20 (stable)

Gem version: 1.8.25

Below is one of these random error:

/home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:165:in `fetch_specs': cannot load such file -- bundler/index (LoadError)
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:67:in`specs'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:52:in `__materialize__'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in`block in materialize'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in`materialize'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `missing_specs'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:72:in`block in run'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/ui.rb:96:in `silence'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:69:in`run'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in`install'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in`invoke_task'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in`start'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in`with_friendly_errors'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/bin/bundle:19:in`load'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`eval'
    from /home/CORP/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@recommendation-test/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'